# Animate a vertical aligned button up and down

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a vertically aligned button that needs to be animated to the top(even a little is fine) and back to its original position.

Codepen: https://jsfiddle.net/ay53dfn2/5/

I have seen some examples that animate the button when it is horizontal but it does not have any effect when I make the button vertical

```css
.test {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
```

```html
<button class="test">Click</button>
```

Comment: something like this? 
https://jsfiddle.net/4gyc7rzp/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
.test {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

.test:focus {
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1
  color: red;
}

@keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: bottom right;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.75);
    opacity: 0.25;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: bottom right;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="test" onclick="this.classList.add('clicked')">Click</button>
```